# CatalogSearch results looking for partial SKU

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, search-criteria, elasticsearch

I need to be able to search by partial string of a SKU, for example, if a SKU of a product is "CUS123.5NYS" the customer may also be able to search by "123.5N", but currently, it only works if I search by initial or end part of the string.

Is it possible to allow search by partial string using some interceptor or preference to override a class?

In the Store configuration I'm using Elasticsearch 5.0+ as Search Engine

Answer (score 2):

By default magento doesn't use wildcards (`*123.5N*`) with ES. Query building logic implemented in class `Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\Query` (need change query type to `query_string`).

Comment: can you elaborate the way,in case i have sku 4005S66Almina and i want to search Almina how to do this?